# jQuery: How to replace the whole DOM with another HTML using .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a problem.
We are doing a Captive Portal.

Go to any site, for example www.php.net
Then in Chrome's console, use this:

```
$("html").load( "https://www.ccc.co.il/Suspend.aspx" );
```

You will notice, the DOM is replaced, but not quite the way it should be:
The wrapper elements of the loaded webpage (title, body for example) are missing!

This causes problems of course on the injected page.

How do I replace the entire initial DOM?
And please dont suggest to me using a link, or normal redirect.
Those are the restrictions, I need to replace the entire DOM tree please.

Thanks!

Comment: One usually replaces content of the `body` element.

Comment: It is an interesting question... can't give you an answer on it directly, but maybe I can suggest a workaround if you state what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What happens if you write valid markup, as in no noscript tags or anchors in the *head* part of your page ?

Comment: @zozo: Well, a firewall serves static, short HTML code on captive portal. If a requested URL/IP is not in the allowed rules, then that HTML is served instead.
Then in that HTML, is where I have the .load call, to inject a full page DOM from the company's website, without redirecting the client, which will change the URL in the browser. I know other ISPs managed to do this, so I want it this way as well - preserving the customer's desired URL in case it has many parameters he would not want to loose while fixing the cause of his problem with the ISP.

Comment: I think you might need an iframe for this

Comment: Would disabling javascript not invalidate your capture page?

Comment: @adeneo I am not sure what do you mean? is the markup invalid as it it now on the loaded webpage? I will try your suggestion of removing the noscript tag on Sunday, as I have no control over the destination webpage right now.

Comment: @AlexK. no, if Javascript is disabled, the client will only see the basic, static message given by the system Firewall, without bells and whistles like chat to the support guys who could help him without calling anyone...

Comment: @chrisvdp: Why do you say that replacing the whole DOM would not work? I will try iframe if I have no other choice left to me...

Comment: Yes, it's invalid, you have a noscript tag and an anchor in the head section, but removing them probably won't help much, as replacing the entire DOM with ajax is usually not the way to go, and there will be issues, as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamentally a feature of browsers.

Here's a snip from the jQuery docs for [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

While I don't recommend what you're suggesting at all, I will attempt to answer your question:

Using a server-side language (like PHP, for example), return documents as parsed json:

```
{
    "head": [head string],
    "body": [body string]
}
```

Then your JavaScript can individually replace each element.
You'll need to switch from `.load()` to something more configurable, like `.ajax()`

Comment: hmmm, well the idea was to use .load with minimum changes to the loaded webpage, or further processing on my part using jquery/javascript.

Thanks for your suggestion, I will either do it this way, or an iframe (whatever will be faster), if no better answers are given by Sunday when the other guy comes back and we could change the code on Firewall and server again.

Comment: Thank you rockerest!
It works well, except for HTTPS websites.. browsers throw various warnings if you try to do this for HTTPS websites (never minding chrome's built in "protections" for Google's websites).

Comment: And the fact that any script execution after replacing the head section, stop :) and I had to write another script in the replaced head, to pick off where the browser stops executing the javascript lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use an iframe in this case as I don't think that you can replace an entire DOM with another.

```
$('body').html("<iframe height=100% width=100% frameBorder=0 src='https://www.ccc.co.il/Suspend.aspx'></iframe>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7EbY/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("https://www.ccc.co.il/Suspend.aspx", function(html){$("html").html(html)});
```

I'm using a regular AJAX function here because it shouldn't strip anything.

Sorry about those 4 `html`s in a row. :P

Comment: Thanks @Scimonster for the idea, I only tried it manually for now (even here on this page) - if I enter this command in console, I still have the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined" which comes from the Sitehood script, trying to select a 'head' element which does not exist in the new DOM... If it doesn't work from console, I suspect it wouldn't work when put in the firewall either. I suspect that in this case, testing in jsfiddle frame is not reliable way to test :)